# What is the pdf of the square of the product of two correlated normal distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Let $x$ and $y$ denote a bivariate normal random vector with zero means, unit variances and correlation coefficient $\rho$. Then, the pdf of $z=xy$ is known to be
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{\frac{\rho z}{1-\rho^2}}K_0\left(\frac{|z|}{1-\rho^2}\right)
\end{equation}
for $-\infty < z < \infty$ and where $K_0(·)$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order zero, then, what is the pdf of $w$ if $w=z^2$?

Thank you in advance!